# Convert util.date to sql.date with date and time in java

Tags: java, sql-server, date

I am trying to convert `java.util.Date` into `java.sql.Date` with below function but this function is giving the time a s 00:00:00.000.

```
private java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
}
```

please help me how can I get both date and time in java.sql.date.
thanks

Comment: Please do your research before posting on stackoverflow: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

Answer (score 1):

Converting `java.util.Date` to `java.sql.Date` will lost the hour,minute and second. 
So if it is possible, I suggest you use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 final String str = "INSERT INTO table (curTime)  VALUES( ?)";
 final PreparedStatement preparedStatement =connection.prepareStatement(str);
  preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
```

you have to use a timestamp for that its not possible with java.sql.date since it removes data related to your time.